Gate fidelity reported in the ibm qcs
Simple question: for some retired ibm quantum computers (for instance lima), how was the gate fidelity measured? I know that they involved a kind of average fidelity, but I would like to know specifically what is the quantity one measures. Is it simply the process fidelity?
(Viz. related to this question, but the general answer there does not say what is the figure of merit is (was) reported in the information table of quantum devices in ibm webpage.)
